# Add click event to optionbutton

Tags: vba, events, outlook

I have a Outlook 2013 macro where I made a form pop up. All objects (buttons, textboxes, optionsbuttons) get added by the code behind in a form.Load() event.

The form has two option buttons with yes/no. If no is pressed then some other buttons, textboxes should be disabled. My question is how to archieve that a event handler is added to these two buttons?

My programmatically added buttons:

```
    y = y + 30
    x = 230
    Set btnOppYes = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1", "btnOppYes")
    With btnOppYes
        .Caption = "Ja"
        .Left = x
        .Top = y
        .Width = 110
        .GroupName = "OppYesNo"
    End With

    x = x + 110
    Set btnOppNo = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1", "btnOppNo")
    With btnOppNo
        .Caption = "Nein"
        .Left = x
        .Top = y
        .Width = 110
        .GroupName = "OppYesNo"
        .Value = True
    End With
```

I tried to add this code, but with no success. There's no msgbox like "test", when I click on the option button:

```
Sub btnOppYes_Click()
    MsgBox ("test")
End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of a form is this? A Form Region? A Windows Form in an add-in? A VBA UserForm? A custom Outlook item form?

Comment: @EricLegault it's a VBA UserForm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event isn't associated with the button when its added dynamically and Outlook doesn't allow access to the CodeModule like Excel does. Here is a workaround.

Paste this code in your userform

```
Dim clsbtnOpp As New Class1
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim btnOppYes As MSForms.OptionButton
    Dim btnOppNo As MSForms.OptionButton
    y = y + 30
    x = 230
    Set btnOppYes = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1", "btnOppYes")
    With btnOppYes
        .Caption = "Ja"
        .Left = x
        .Top = y
        .Width = 110
        .GroupName = "OppYesNo"
    End With
    Set clsbtnOpp.btnOppYes = btnOppYes

    x = x + 110
    Set btnOppNo = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1", "btnOppNo")
    With btnOppNo
        .Caption = "Nein"
        .Left = x
        .Top = y
        .Width = 110
        .GroupName = "OppYesNo"
        .Value = True
    End With
    Set clsbtnOpp.btnOppNo = btnOppNo
End Sub
```

And create a new class called **Class1** and paste this code in it

```
Public WithEvents btnOppYes As MSForms.OptionButton
Public WithEvents btnOppNo As MSForms.OptionButton
Private Sub btnOppYes_click()
    MsgBox "You clicked yes"
    UserForm1.TextBox1.Enabled = True
End Sub
Private Sub btnOppNo_click()
    MsgBox "You clicked no"
    UserForm1.TextBox1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Run your form and test. You can play around with this and tailor it to your needs